# How to make cmdline in for loop not break after first Spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

in `scrapy` is there a way to run the `cmdline.execute()` function in a `for` loop? Below is the example. When trying to execute, the script stops after the first iteration of `for link in links`, only indicating `INFO: Closing spider (finished)`. How could I make the script return to the loop without breaking?

**Execute.py:**

```
from scrapy import cmdline

links = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/", "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/"]

for link in links:
    command = "scrapy crawl quotes1 -a source_url="
    command += link
    cmdline.execute(command.split())
```

**Spider.py**

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpiderS(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = []
        urls.append("%s" % self.source_url)
        print(urls)
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the list of links to the `start_urls` [attribute](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_urls) in your Spider.

```
class QuotesSpiderS(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/",
                  "http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code does not work however.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Maybe that's what you are looking for.